# Img tag with local file:/// URL is not shown in the Microsoft Edge web browser

Tags: html, image, windows-10, microsoft-edge

In my desktop application I create a temporary HTML file (that is designed to let users print a report) that is then displayed via a default web browser. This HTML file is saved in a temp folder, for example: `C:/Users/UserName/AppData/Local/Temp`

This works in all web browsers (surprisingly even including IE) but Microsoft's another creation, [Edge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Edge), gives me a blank image icon

[image]

for the following:

```
<img width='24' height='24' style='border: none;' alt='Print'
src="file:///C:/Users/UserName/AppData/Local/Temp/printicon.gif"></img>
```

Any idea why this fails?

PS. Obviously that `gif` file exists and is openable.

**FOLLOW-UP:** Upon further testing, I discovered the reason why Edge was blocking my image. I added the following to the top of the HTML mark-up

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<!-- saved from url=(0038)http://www.samplewebsite.com/index.htm -->
<html>
<head>
```

to prevent IE from showing this:

[image]

Mind you, the reason for that message was just this line of code for the "Print" button:

```
javascript:window.print();
```

So if I remove the `<!-- saved from ... -->` line, Edge seems to display my images. But I obviously can't do it, because I need it to work with older IE.

Comment: What does F12 tools say about the file?

Comment: @Dai: Sorry, this is the first time I loaded up Edge. What shall I be looking for in F12 tools?

Comment: @c00000fd I just tested with Edge using an html file and an image in my appdata temp folder without an issue. Maybe some security setting perhaps?

Comment: @JonathanGray: Oh, wow. Thanks. Let me dig into it.

Comment: I think I may know what the issue is. If the file was downloaded from the internet, it is blocked for execution by default. Edge may be more aware of the attribute. Try right-clicking on the image file itself and go into the properties to see if it's "blocked".

Comment: As a follow-up to my previous comment; I just attempted this myself by downloading a .gif off of the internet and left it "blocked". This did not seem to make a difference. It still worked.

Comment: @JonathanGray: No, that was not the issue. The GIF file is actually a locally installed file. So it doesn't have a "blocked" NTFS flag. But I've figured out what Edge doesn't like...

Comment: I added the following to the top of the HTML `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<!-- saved from url=(0038)http://www.samplewebsite.com/index.htm -->` to prevent that "idiotic" IE popup that says, "Internet Explorer restricted this web page from running scripts and Active X controls". Mind you that my HTML has no Active X plug ins. It has a one line of script for the print button, i.e. `"javascript:window.print();"`

Comment: So if I remove that `<!-- saved from -->` line Edge seems to open images OK, but I obviously can't do it, since I need it to work with IE. Damn Microsoft! Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Ahh.. In your case I would run it off of an actual webserver. You could install xampp for an easy-to-use approach, or use NodeJS (which I believe you can run standalone). There are a bunch of others to choose from such as nginx.

Comment: @JonathanGray: Yeah, that's one way. Although this seems like an overkill for such a trivial issue. I'd rather go for a browser detection method and show user a popup that their web browser is incompatible and then direct them to download Chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I got it solved (once I knew what's causing it.) Actually found [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537628(v=vs.85).aspx) that gave me the clue. So if I do this, it will work with Edge and IE:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<!-- saved from url=(0016)http://localhost -->
<html>
```

Comment: In my case I could not render a png in Edge or IE but it would render in Chrome.  The problem was that the png was actually a jpg renamed as a png but not encoded as a png.  Chrome was figuring it out but Edge and IE could not.  Encoding it as an actual png fixed the issue.

Comment: @TimSexton you solved my issue today.

Answer (score 0):

i experienced a similar issue
my my-file.html had been corrupted
i copied contents of my my-file.html an other .html file and the issue is solved and my image was shown
it took more time than two hours :)